# What do $I_{x2}$ and $I_{x3}$ represent in this Circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, notation

[image]

I thought it would be Ix2 = I2 or Ix2 = 2I2. if that makes sense.
The question asks for Voltage across R2 but i dont want an answer, i just need to know what those two symbols stand for so i can get to an answer. please and thank you

Comment: It's just a different label. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

They are the currents through the circuit branches indicated by the arrows in the diagram.

It would have been confusing to label these currents $I_2$ and $I_3$ because those symbols are already being used to label two of the ideal current sources in the diagram.

They could equally well have been labeled $I_a$ and $I_{\rm test}$ without changing the physics of the problem.